# Email regex with character limit (without lookahead)

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I have a regex: "\b[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b" for validating email addresses within ASP.NET.

I would like to be able to limit the overall number of characters between 6 & 100 characters. I'm coding for IE 6, so how can this be done without using a lookahead?

Many thanks

Comment: Not the answer you want, but dont forget single quotes (') bob.o'conner@xx.com is a valid email. Is there a reason why you want to do it all as regex?

Comment: On a related note, but not answering your question.  There is some guidance here: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3696#section-3 that might help you create an expression that doesn't cause email addresses to erroneously fail validation.

Comment: Why can't you use lookahead with IE6? Is there a bug I'm not aware of?

Comment: That won't allow '+' in the name part, or [internationalised top level domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_country_code_top-level_domain).

Answer (score 1):

Why not just check the length separately, instead of trying to shoehorn it into the regex?

Comment: exactly, easier to understand what is happening with the code as well.

Comment: probably because he wants it as a regular expression validator in .NET to fire on the client side to avoid postbacks. A custom validator would work, but then you have to write that. Personally, at that rate I find the expression more straightforward. However, I realize that you can't really validate an email (without lookaheads) ensuring that the entire string is between a certain character limit.

Comment: Yes, I need to run this client-side for an MVC application. Ideally I don't want to have to split the validation down into two validation rules, one for pattern matching & another for length.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a spin:

This requires the **username** to be between 6 and 600 characters. Without knowing how long the domain may be, I don't think you're going to be able to limit it effectively without a lookahead (or behind). The only possible workaround I can think of would be to set arbitrary limits on each: say 300 for the username, and 300 for the domain.

```
^(#?[_a-zA-Z0-9+-](\.?[_a-zA-Z0-9+-]{5,599})*)@([a-zA-Z0-9]+(-(?!-)|[a-zA-Z0-9\.])*?[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.([0-9]{1,3}|[a-zA-Z]{2,3}|(aero|arpa|asia|coop|info|jobs|mobi|museum|name|travel)))$
```